# How to change part in the url and not refresh in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to change the url in vue without reloading the page?

for example, I have `https://www.example.com/en/foo/bar`, and I want to change `en` to `de`, `https://www.example.com/de/foo/bar`, but I don't want nothing to change and recalculate in the page.

Is it possible to do in vue?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please describe the use case in more detail. Solutions may depend on the surrounding circumstances.

Comment: I want to change the lang in the page but I don't want to redirect/reload the page. so I use i18n to do it. the values of i18n are recalculate. but I also want to change the url. so I don't need and wont to refresh the page

Comment: You dont need Vue for it. [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: makes no sense, if lang is rendered in english and then you want it in german, if you dont re[load/render] how would it possibly change the text?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: If vue state contains languages locals, it will automatically recalculates labels/text

Comment: OP said **does not want to recalculate** (whatever that means), pushState is the solution then, if it works :/

Comment: IMO: I think he does not want to reload the entire page but only refresh language related items, Solution from @Dmitry works

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry for misleading. I mean not recalculate by change the url.

Comment: To follow @Dmitry, you can find a How-To for VueJs here [https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/enhance-router-to-work-with-spas/]